# IE7 converting bracket notation to . notation in javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I have this line of code (where 'e' is a click event):

```
var type = $(e.currentTarget.parentNode)[0].classList[0];
```

which is producing this error in IE7 (using Companion.JS to report errors):

```
'0.classList.0' is null or not an object
```

I tried the following variations on my code, but get the same result:

```
var type = $(e.currentTarget).parent()[0].classList[0];
var type = $(e.currentTarget).parent()['0'].classList['0'];
```

This code works in the latest Chrome and Firefox browsers. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: what are you attempting to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to get the first class to determine the 'type' of object that has been clicked on. I have two types, and they have different classes to differentiate them and somewhat different behaviors.

Comment: why don't you use jquery's `hasClass` or `.is`?

Comment: I was trying to avoid having to make a switch statement to check all the possible types in case I add more in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check the `.length` of `$(e.currentTarget.parentNode)`, you might have to add a condition for IE because the `currentTarget` is inconsistent with other browsers.

Also, classList is not supported in IE.

[Code with classList does not work in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098406/code-with-classlist-does-not-work-in-ie)

parse the `.attr('class')` or `[0].className`

Comment: Yeah, classList was the issue. I replaced it with `className.split(/\s+/)[0]`