# Alternatives for list methods for IE?

Tags: javascript, list, internet-explorer, method-missing

I am looking for a way to do `node.classList.contains("foo")` in Internet Exploder 7-9 without needing to refactor major portions of my code. This method is present in all other browsers (even IE10).

I have found [Code with classList does not work in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8098406/522479) but I dont understand how I would use this for replacing the `.contains()` method.

I already do have code that let's me run isolated code for certain browsers only, so giving IE some extra or different code isn't a problem.

Is there a way to add said method via `classList`'s prototype or some other handy way to work with `className`?

Comment: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#classlist

Comment: The MDN Documentation on [**element.classList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList) shows a JavaScript shim for IE8-9 if that is of some help. I know it doesn't show IE7 but its hopefully a start. Your biggest problem will be `...without needing to refactor major portions of my code` If you need to support IE7-9 then I think you are just better of not to be using any IE10-only compatible features in the first place and `classList` is one of the features only support IE10+ and other browsers off course.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you! That list is some sweet wizardry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This just isn't possible.

At first glance, you'd have thought you'd have been able to patch your own `classList` implementation into `HTMLElement` if it didn't exist already;

```
if (!("classList" in document.createElement("div"))) {
    HTMLElement.prototype.classList = {
        contains: function () {

        }
    };
}
```

However:

1. Your `contains` implementation has no way to access the DOMElement (`this` is the `classList` object, not the element
2. Extending DOM objects in older IE [*just doesn't work*](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

---

Your *only* option is to replace all your usage of `classList` with your own wrapper function, which uses the `classList` functionality if available, and falls back to your own implementation if it doesn't.

```
var classListWrapper = (function () {
    if ("classList" in document.createElement("div")) {
      return {
        add: function (el, class) {
          el.className.add(class);
        },
        remove: function (el, class) {
          el.className.remove(class);
        },
        // etc.
      }
    } else {
      return {
        add: function (el, class) {
          el.className += ' ' + class;
        },
        remove: function (el, class) {
          el.className = (' ' + el.className + ' ').replace(' ' + class + ' ', ' ');
        },
        // etc.
      };
    }
}());
```

... and then in your code use `classListWrapper.add(element, class)` instead.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the hows and whys of this problem! I've used a similar solution to what you suggested with one of the snippets Bergi provided.