# Javascript function which uses .classList and .toggle is not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have a function which simply changes the class of an element based on a click. It works fine everywhere but IE8. Any assistance would be great!

This is the function:

```
function attachToggleReportType (elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('change', toggleReportType);
}

function toggleReportType () {
var reportOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.report'),
    reportIncToggle = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle');

reportSample({
    href: this.getAttribute('data-sample-report-link'),
    src: this.getAttribute('data-sample-report-image')
});

reportIncToggle.forEach(toggleInclude);

    var report_type = $(this).find('input[type=radio]').val();
    report_type = ( report_type == 1 ? 'Verified' : 'Claims');
    // analytics.updateType(report_type);
}

function toggleInclude (item) {
    item.classList.toggle('notIncluded');
    item.classList.toggle('included');
}
```

HTML

```
<li class="larger toggle notIncluded">
    <span>Cross-Canada lien search</span>
    <br>
    Exclusive to CARPROOF <strong>Verified</strong> reports, we’ll tell you if there’s money owing on the vehicle.
</li>
```

Comment: Since you're already using jQuery, simply use `toggleClass()`.  It will overcome browser inconsistencies.

Comment: [`classList` is one of the many things IE8 does not support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Browser_compatibility). And neither does IE9. Either load up a polyfill, at least one exists, or use jQuery or some other library instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code with classList does not work in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098406/code-with-classlist-does-not-work-in-ie)

Comment: http://caniuse.com/ is your friend

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098406/code-with-classlist-does-not-work-in-ie and probably many more. You should do a little google search before asking a question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using jQuery, which provides cross-browser support for manipulating classes on elements. Also `forEach` is not supported in IE 8

[**classList** browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=classList)

[**forEach** browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=forEach)

jQuery

```
$('.elementClass').toggleClass('className');
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ofx4zk1h/) (without jQuery and supports IE8)

Answer (score 0):

[`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is [not supported by IE8 or 9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist). Since you are already using `jQuery`, you should just use: [jQuery.toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

```
$(item).toggleClass('notIncluded included');
```