# Get classList from event

Tags: javascript

I have a simple JS event:

```
var changeAddress = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-open');

if (changeAddress.length) {
    var a = 0;
    while (a < changeAddress.length) {
        changeAddress[a].addEventListener('click', function () {
            console.log(this); // Here i want to get classList
            document.querySelector('.modal').removeAttribute('hidden');
        });
        a++;
    }
}
```

How can I get classList from `this`?

It's not necessary get it from `this` or throw `classList`. I just want to get all class names of element on which event is triggered. Thanks!

Comment: If the code that you've written is in event handler, then you can directly use event.target.classList

Comment: What is `this` in that context (where you do `console.log(this)`)?  You're not inside the click handler at that point, why do you want the `classList` there?  *Inside* the click handler however, you can do `this.classList`.

Comment: And the problem is...

Comment: The place you want to get the `classList` is outside of the event handler, so no event has been triggered at that point. All you have is an array of elements in `changeAddress`.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko don't know ho to get classList from event.

Comment: classList of what elemetn do you need?

Comment: It is not clear from which event. Inside click handlers or this whole function is being called on some event.

Comment: @RocketHazmat sorry, I put `console.log(this)` inside event

Comment: @AleshaOleg: It's actually still outside the event.

Comment: @RocketHazmat fixed one more time:)

Comment: @AleshaOleg: So, what do you see from your `console.log`?  Since it's inside the event, you should be able to do `this.classList`.

Comment: @Rhumborl fixed it

Comment: @GangadharJannu thanks! `event.target.classList` work! Could you please answer this question? I will mark it as answer

Comment: @RocketHazmat it's `undefined`, but `event.target.className` works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `event handler callback` you can get `event` as a parameter.
With 'event' param we can get list of classes using either className or classList.

1. **Using classList**: `event.target.classList` will directly returns list of class names in an Array.
2. **Using className**: `event.target.className` will return string representation of class names with space as seperator.
   So you can use `event.target.className.split("/\s")` which will return array of class names.

---

We can use className or classList.
className is supported by older browsers but modification (add, toggle, remove...) of classes is a tedious 
task, so classList is introduced and is easy to use.

However the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classList) property is [not widely supported yet](http://caniuse.com/classlist)

Please refer [Code with classList does not work in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098406/code-with-classlist-does-not-work-in-ie) for cross browser support