# How to change a property of a CSS class dynamically using javascript (no JQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I am trying to perform a transition (reducing or extending the height of a DIV).  I would like to know how to go about altering a specific property (in this case 'height') associated with a specific class involved in the transition before invoking the transition by changing the CSS classname  associated with the element using  javascript?

So in the example below, I would like to change the 'height' property of '. sboxopen' from 130px to 360px.  Then invoking the transition by changing the element's class name - > Object.className = 'sboxopen';

CSS classes:

```
.sbox{
height: 0px;
transition: height 1s ease-out;
overflow: hidden;
}
.sboxopen{
height: 130px;
transition: height 1s ease-out;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

TRANSISTION USING JAVASCRIPT:

```
 Object.className = 'sbox';
```

or

```
 Object.className = 'sboxopen';
```

If I cannot change the property of the classes, how do I go about creating a new CSS class dynamically using javascript so that I can incorporate the desired 'height' property for my desired transition?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098406/code-with-classlist-does-not-work-in-ie in another form

Comment: Your approach won't work; if you need the height to be dynamic, then you should just manipulate the height directly (`el.css.height = '360px'`). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style.

Comment: No. As I am trying to perform a transition that will not work. tried it

Comment: Point is, you can't really manipulate the individual properties of your CSS class using JavaScript, and creating new CSS classes in JS, while possible, is a lot of unnecessary work. I would check out https://gomakethings.com/how-to-add-transition-animations-to-vanilla-javascript-show-and-hide-methods/ for a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what triggers your animation, but let's say it's a `click` on each of the `.sbox` elements.

As you can't change the CSS, you can instead use the script to add an inline style height using `.style.height`.

Here is a snippet:

```js
var sboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".sbox");

sboxes.forEach(function(box, index){
  box.onclick = function(){
    box.style.height = "360px";
    box.className = 'sboxopen';
  }
})
```

```css
.sbox {
  height: 0px;
  transition: height 1s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 8px solid gray; /* Added for better visibility */
}

.sboxopen {
  height: 130px;
  transition: height 1s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 8px solid gray; /* Added for better visibility */
}
```

```html
<div class='sbox'>Box 1</div>
<br>
<div class='sbox'>Box 2</div>
<br>
<div class='sbox'>Box 3</div>
```

⋅
⋅
⋅

Then, we can imagine using custom heights from a custom attribute, for each of the `.sbox`:

```js
var sboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".sbox");

sboxes.forEach(function(box, index){
  box.onclick = function(){
    box.style.height = box.getAttribute('myHeight');
    box.className = 'sboxopen';
  }
})
```

```css
.sbox {
  height: 0px;
  transition: height 1s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 8px solid gray; /* Added for better visibility */
}

.sboxopen {
  height: 130px;
  transition: height 1s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 8px solid gray; /* Added for better visibility */
}
```

```html
<div class='sbox' myHeight='30px'>Box 1</div>
<br>
<div class='sbox' myHeight='60px'>Box 2</div>
<br>
<div class='sbox' myHeight='360px'>Box 3</div>
```

Feel free to comment if any.

Hope it helps.